# django shell xlrd.open_workbook() Errno 13

Tags: python, django, shell, xlrd

I have a set of data that I import from an excel spreadsheet. It is a requirement.
**It works fine on other PCs** but on this one I get the error message:

```
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 111, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

I am opening the file the usual way:

```
import xlrd
xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('spreadsheet' + '.xlsx')
```

I tried everything

- opening another file (no other excel file can be opened)
- reinstalling python (and pip installing the django and xlrd modules)
- restarting the PC

I can assure the file is not open and from the python shell it works fine.

But within the manage.py shell it fails. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try specifying the mode while opening? - `xlrd.open_workbook('spreadsheet.xlsx',mode='r')`

Comment: mode is not a keyword, but even with 'r' it doesn't work

Comment: I am quite certain it has something to do with the virtual environment, on this PC it has been installed in venv but it has moved because of git repo activities. How can I either put it on venv?

Comment: I just tried to run it in a venv but the same behaviour as before is the result.